# Emscripten: how can i compile a c file with an intrinsic header like immintrin.h?

Tags: c, sse, webassembly, intrinsics, emscripten

I am trying to compile CLBG benchmarks with emscripten (C to WASM). However, most of them has included intrinsic headers (like <immintrin.h>) and that gave me a lot of errors (let`s use nbody.c as an example) like this:

`nbody.c:137:20: error: use of undeclared identifier '__m128d' static alignas(__m128d) double`

I already tried to compile with these flags

`emcc nbody.c -o nbody.js -O2 -s WASM=1 -msse2 -msimd128`

and it compiles. However, when I tried to run nbody.js with nodejs, it doesn`t work. I have also tried to run nodejs with

`--experimental-wasm-simd`

like this [git](https://github.com/adrianchang/Javascript-Parallel-Library) tells, but it also doesn't work. It says:

> `failed to asynchronously prepare wasm: CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Compiling function #4:"main" failed: invalid value type 'Simd128', enable with --experimental-wasm-simd @+422`
> `CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Compiling function #4:"main" failed: invalid value type 'Simd128', enable with --experimental-wasm-simd @+422`
> `RuntimeError: abort(CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Compiling function #4:"main" failed: invalid value type 'Simd128', enable with --experimental-wasm-simd @+422).`
> `Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.`

Can anyone give me a hand? I am not understanding if this is already possible to do.

Comment: I suspect you'll have to rewrite the code.  Intrinsics are inherently specific to a particular CPU architecture, as they invoke specific CPU instructions, and WASM is effectively a completely different architecture from x86.  The code you link seems to provide a separate set of intrinsics, so you'd have to rewrite the x86 code to use the WASM data types and intrinsics instead.  It's the same sort of thing you'd have to do if you were trying to port the code to run on ARM.

Comment: [SIMD Everywhere](https://github.com/simd-everywhere/simde) might be relevant, depending on the specific intrinsics being used.

Comment: It appears you're doing everything right, but either using old Emscripten or old Node.js - the SIMD spec was in development, so any version mismatch but result in those opcode errors.

Try to update both Emscripten and Node.js to latest and see how it goes.

Comment: @RReverser, I have all updated but still doesn't work. I preferred not lost more time in this problem and search for other benchmarks that don't use intrinsic. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: @JoãoMacedo It's strange, SSE2 intrinsics definitely work for me, so it seems to be a matter of either old version (which you ruled out) or some missing includes.

Comment: Oh, wait, I just noticed the 2nd runtime error you got. As it says, you just need to enable SIMD with --experimental-wasm-simd when invoking the code - I assume you're doing that in Node.js? If so, just pass this extra param like `node --experimental-wasm-simd your.js` and it should work.

Comment: @RReverser I already did that, and give me the same error. I compiled my.js with "-s ASSERIONS=1" to give me more information. When I run my.js with nodejs, it gives me the error "invalid simd opcode"

Comment: "invalid simd opcode" definitely indicates either old toolchain or old Node.js - this is because the SIMD proposal got changed few months ago and some opcodes are encoded differently. If you try latest Emscripten (2.0.16) and latest Node.js (16.0.0), I guarantee you won't see this error.

Answer (score 2):

Add these compile flags to C and CXX Flags

```
-fPIC -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -msse2 -msimd128 -experimental-wasm-simd
```